# Amplify voltage controlled current source in a instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, instrumentation-amplifier

I need to apply a current in the body by two electrodes and then analyze this signal, I will receive the signal by other 2 electrodes and amplify using a instrumentation amplifier using three Op Amps (TL084CN).
But, I can not to simulate the offset by voltage controlled current source in a instrumentation amplifier.

I am using the topology described in the article "Design of an Instrumentation Amplifier - Justin Bauer", where the gain is 10.
Example:
[image]
With Vin = 500mV peak to peak, then Vout = 5V peak to peak. (Gain = 10).
Putting 5V DC on Vref, then Vout is oscillating between + 10V and 0V.
All right.

**My problem is:**
Using a current source (Mirrored Modified Howland Current Source (MMHCS)) where +Iout = 1mA and -Iout = -1mA.
With a initial voltage source where amplitude = 2V and the frequency = 1kHz.
**I can not to simulate the offset.**
**Vout is always between + 10.5V and -10.5V.**
[image]
I tried to apply in Vref 10V, 5V, 2V, but nothing works.
The Vout still varies from -10.5V to + 10.5V.
The Vref only distorts the voltage signal.
I want the **Vout** varies between (say) **+ 20V and 0V**, it will use the AD converter Arduino Uno, that just read positive signs.
I am using Proteus 8.5.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Sorry my poor english, i don't speak english.

Bibliography:

http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring15/group05/uploads/4/7/5/1/47515639/ece_480_app_note_justin_bauer.pdf

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258327515_High_Accurate_Howland_Current_Source_Output_Constraints_Analysis

Comment: what resistance are you modelling for the body.

Comment: I think you don't need two current sources, just one will do. Electrode 2 should be connected to ground.  Also, the human body is an antenna for RF signals, so you should have input filters on Electrodes 3 and 4. There could also be DC offsets caused by differing skin-electrode electrolytic potentials, so I would AC-couple the amplifier inputs (unless you want to measure these DC offsets too!).

Comment: The amplifier's gain-setting resistor, R7, will probably need to be adjusted in real-world use, to keep the output signal within the range of your power supplies.  This is usually done by replacing R7 with a digipot (digital potentiometer). The digipot is controlled by your computer device (Arduino, etc.).

Comment: I'm not modeling any resistance to the body. I'm connecting the current source outputs directly to the instrumentation amplifier inputs. As if the body had no resistance.

Comment: That makes no sense.  Those inputs have giaohm impedences

Comment: Why are you building a discrete instrumentation amp out of op amps? Why not just use an in amp IC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not modeling any resistance to the body. I'm connecting the
>   current source outputs directly to the instrumentation amplifier
>   inputs.

That looks like the problem - you are trying to inject a mA into a giga ohm (the input impedance of the InAmp) and not surprisingly the current driver cannot force 1 mA into 1 Gohm. It would be able to if the power rails were +/- 1 million volts but they aren't and cannot be.

Try putting 100 ohm across the output of the two drivers. This then forces a voltage of 100 mV and, with a gain of ten you will get 1V out. Your expectations of 20V out are unreasonable given that the InAmp power rail is 12 volt.

One more thing - you will need a galvanic connection between the driver circuit 0 V and the InAmp 0 V. The human body (a real one) might facilitate this via other "connections" but for your simulation you'll need one.

Try 100 kohm.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will research about galvanic isolation.